# Python Script to Delete Mails on Gmail from Categories

Tags: python, imap

I want to create a script to access a gmail accouunt , go to a particular category i.e 'Promotions' and delete mails from a sender.

So far I made this :

```
import imaplib

# login to your Gmail account
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('mail@gmail.com', 'password')

# select the Promotions category
mail.select('Promotions')

# search for emails from a particular sender
result, data = mail.search(None, 'FROM "sender@gmail.com')

# delete the emails
for num in data[0].split():
    mail.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
mail.expunge()

# logout from your Gmail account
mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

I kept getting this errors on pycharm

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\Documents\Python Tutorials\Projects\mail_script.py", line 11, in 
result, data = mail.search(None, 'FROM "sender@gmail.com"')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 734, in search
typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, *criteria)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 1230, in _simple_command
return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 968, in _command
raise self.error("command %s illegal in state %s, "
imaplib.IMAP4.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED`

Comment: Promotions isn’t a mailbox name.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import imaplib

# login to your Gmail account
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('mail@gmail.com', 'password')

# select the Promotions category
mail.select('Promotions')

# select all messages from the sender
mail.select('INBOX')
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'FROM "sender@gmail.com"')

# delete the emails
if data[0]:
    for uid in data[0].split():
        mail.uid('store', uid, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
    mail.expunge()

# logout from your Gmail account
mail.close()
mail. Logout()
```

Comment: You just posted my code back?

Comment: According to the IMAP protocol, the SEARCH command is only valid when a mailbox has been selected.
To fix this, i chnaged the line mail. Select('Promotions') `result, data = mail. Search(None, 'FROM "sender@gmail.com"')`